# texreg: numbers as text instead of math

Tags: latex, texreg

I am using texreg for regression output.  I would like to align on decimals in the table.  However, all numbers are in math mode, between '$' characters.  Is there an option to only enclose the significance stars in '$', leaving the numbers as regular text?

Comment: Can you show your table? Maybe an `S` column from siunitx could help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am using LyX, and it looks like I cannot easily override the provided column options.

Comment: There are `texreg` arguments for decimal point alignment, such as `dcolumn` and `siunitx`. Have you considered those?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Used stringr to modify the output of texreg.  For anyone interested:

```
tex <- texreg(list(model1,model2,model3,model4),
       digits = 3,
       stars=c(0.1,0.05,0.01,0.001),
       symbol='+')
#
# convert numbers to text, grabbing stars and keeping between math symbols.
library(stringr)
newTex <- str_replace_all(tex,"\\$\\(?-?\\d+(,\\d+)*(\\.\\d+(e\\d+)?)?\\)?\\^?\\{?(\\*+)?\\+?\\}?\\$",
                          function(x) {
                            if(str_detect(x,"\\^")) {
                              ret <- sub("^","$^",sub("$","",x,fixed=T),fixed=T)
                            } else {
                              ret <- gsub("$","",x,fixed=T)
                            }
                            return(ret)
                          })
```